# I would like to get the loggedin user info

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my problem. Am new with angularjs and i want to get infos on the loggedin user. So i can for instance display it. I do not know how or where to start from here is my main angular controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

myApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/api/meetups', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
      controller: 'loginController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/prive', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/prive.html',
      controller: 'userController',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/logout', {
      controller: 'logoutController',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/register', {
      templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
      controller: 'registerController',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .when('/one', {
      template: '<h1>This is page one!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: true}
    })
    .when('/two', {
      template: '<h1>This is page two!</h1>',
      access: {restricted: false}
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });
});

myApp.run(function ($rootScope, $location, $route, AuthService) {
  $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart',
    function (event, next, current) {
      AuthService.getUserStatus()
      .then(function(){
        if (next.access.restricted && !AuthService.isLoggedIn()){
          $location.path('/login');
          $route.reload();
        }
      });
  });
});


myApp.controller('meetupsController', ['$scope', '$resource', 'AuthService', function ($scope, $resource, AuthService) {
  var Meetup = $resource('/api/meetups');
$scope.meetups = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.meetups = results;
  });



  $scope.createMeetup = function () {
    var meetup = new Meetup();
    meetup.name = $scope.meetupName;
     meetup.text = $scope.username;
    meetup.$save(function (result) {
      $scope.meetups.push(result);
      $scope.meetupName = '';
      $scope.username = '';
    });
  }





}]);
myApp.controller('userController', ['$scope', '$resource', function ($scope, $resource) {
/*  var Meetup = $resource('/api/user');
$scope.users = []

  Meetup.query(function (results) {
    $scope.users = results;
  });
*/

var Meetup = $resource('/api/user', {},{
  query: {method: 'get', isArray: true}
});
$scope.users = []
$scope.text='mikyas';
  Meetup.query({text: $scope.text}).$promise.then(function (results) {
    $scope.users = results;
  }, function(error) {
  // console.log(error);
   $scope.meetups = [];
});

}]);
```

Can anyone provide code please.

Answer (score 0):

That is what a Service is for in Angular. Here is an example Authentication Service I am using in one of my Applications. If you want to keep a User logged in after closing the application you should also store the user in the local storage.

```
 app.factory('AuthService', ['$q', '$http', 'LocalStorageService',
  function($q, $http, LocalStorageService) {
    var service = {};

    service.user = LocalStorageService.get("AUTH_USER", null);

    service.isLoggedIn = function(){
        return service.user != null && service.user != undefined && service.user != "";
    }

    service.checkLogged = function(){
        return $http.get(APPCONFIG.apiAccessPoint + "/user/" + service.user._id + "/isLogged").then(function(response){
            if(!response.data.success || !response.data.logged){
                service.logout();
                return false;
            }
            else{
                return true;
            }
        }, function(response){
            service.logout();
            return false;
        });
    }

    service.login = function(name, password){
        return $http.post(APPCONFIG.apiAccessPoint + "/user/login", {name: name, password: password}).then(function (response){
            if(response.data.success){ 
                LocalStorageService.set('AUTH_USER', response.data.data);
                $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.data.data.token;
                service.user = response.data.data; 
            } 
            return response.data;
        }, function (response){
            if(response.status == 400 || response.data.error_code == "VAL_ERROR"){
                return response.data;
            }
            else{
                return $q.reject();
            }
        });
    }

    service.logout = function(){
        // remove token from local storage and clear http auth header
        LocalStorageService.deleteValue("AUTH_USER");
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = '';
        service.user = null;
    }

    return service;
}]);
```

And this is how you would use the service in a controller (for example showing a profile):

```
app.controller('ProfileViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'AuthService', 'UserService',
function($scope, $routeParams, AuthService, UserService) {

     $scope.isLogged = AuthService.isLoggedIn();
     $scope.user = null;
     $scope.notFound = false;
     $scope.ownProfile = false;

     $scope.user = UserService.getUser($routeParams.user).then(function(response){
         if(response.success){
             $scope.user = response.data;
             $scope.notFound = response.data == undefined;
             if(!$scope.notFound && $scope.isLogged){
                 $scope.ownProfile = $scope.user._id == AuthService.user._id;
             }
         }
         else{
             console.log(response.data);
         }
     });


}]);
```

Or with the login page:

```
 app.controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', '$route', 'AuthService',
  function($scope, $route, AuthService) {

    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.login = function(){
        AuthService.login($scope.user.name, $scope.user.password).then(function(response){
            if(response.success){ 
                $route.reload();
            }
            else{
                console.log("Wrong User or password...");
            }
        });
    }
}]);
```

Comment: 10q for your precious time but tell me do i add your code in my angular controller ? please help me

Comment: I added a example how you would use a Service with in a Controller.

Comment: I get Unknown provider: UserServiceProvider <- UserService <- ProfileViewCtrl

Comment: Well, the UserService is something you would have to code. It is there to perform CRUD operations against and API for example. Maybe a good start for you would be to first read up on where and how to use services and factories. I am not providing a link now since google puts out a massive amount of content on that subject.